Subject: Issue with Email Forwarding - Original "To" Field is Missing
I have implemented an email forwarding feature in my Laravel 9 application using PHP 8.0. The forwarding works, but when the email is forwarded, the original "To" field and recipient information are removed or altered. Instead, the forwarded email appears as if it was sent from the CRM account, losing the original structure of the email.
public function emailForward(Request $request)
    {
        $imap = new Imap([
            'host' => config('app.mail_host'),
            'user' => config('app.support_user_id'),
            'password' => config('app.support_user_password'),
            'port' => config('app.mail_port'),
            'ssl' => config('app.mail_ssl'),
            'novalidatecert' => config('app.mail_novalidatecert'),
        ]);
        // return $imap->countMessages();
        // Fetch the email
        $message = $imap->getMessage(203);

        // Extract the email body
        $body = '';
        if ($message->isMultipart()) {
            foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($message) as $part) {
                if (stripos($part->contentType, 'text/plain') !== false) {
                    $body = $part->getContent();
                    break;
                } elseif (stripos($part->contentType, 'text/html') !== false) {
                    // $body = $part->getContent();
                    $body = nl2br($part->getContent());
                }
            }
        } else {
            // $body = $message->getContent();
            $body = nl2br($part->getContent());
        }
        

        // Forward the email
        Mail::raw($body, function ($mail) use ($message) {
            $mail
                ->from('demo@zyz.com', 'Amazon')
                ->to('demo-1@abc.com', 'Jhon')
                // ->to('husai9.sid@gmail.com', 'Jhon')
                ->subject('Fwd:alt.xyz[enter image description here][1].com');
        });

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Email forwarded successfully!']);
    }



In emailing today you shouldn't be sending emails on behalf of just anybody, you should only be sending from the domains you controls. If you don't, the likelihood of your emails disappearing in a black hole is getting close to 100%.

The issue arises because when you forward an email in your Laravel application, you are manually constructing the forwarded email using Mail::raw. This does not preserve the original "To", "From", "CC", or "BCC" fields as they appear in the original email. Instead, the email is sent as if it were a new email from the email address defined in the from() method.
To solve this problem and preserve the original structure of the email, you need to include the original headers, such as the original "To" and "From" fields, in the body of the forwarded email. Here's how you can modify your implementation to address this:
public function emailForward(Request $request)
{
    $imap = new Imap([
        'host' => config('app.mail_host'),
        'user' => config('app.support_user_id'),
        'password' => config('app.support_user_password'),
        'port' => config('app.mail_port'),
        'ssl' => config('app.mail_ssl'),
        'novalidatecert' => config('app.mail_novalidatecert'),
    ]);

    // Fetch the email
    $message = $imap->getMessage(203);

    // Extract the email headers and body
    $originalHeaders = [
        'From' => $message->getHeader('from'),
        'To' => $message->getHeader('to'),
        'Subject' => $message->getHeader('subject'),
    ];

    $body = '';
    if ($message->isMultipart()) {
        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($message) as $part) {
            if (stripos($part->contentType, 'text/plain') !== false) {
                $body = $part->getContent();
                break;
            } elseif (stripos($part->contentType, 'text/html') !== false) {
                $body = nl2br($part->getContent());
            }
        }
    } else {
        $body = nl2br($message->getContent());
    }

    // Create the forwarded email content
    $forwardedBody = "Forwarded message:\n\n";
    $forwardedBody .= "From: {$originalHeaders['From']}\n";
    $forwardedBody .= "To: {$originalHeaders['To']}\n";
    $forwardedBody .= "Subject: {$originalHeaders['Subject']}\n\n";
    $forwardedBody .= "---- Original Message ----\n\n";
    $forwardedBody .= $body;

    // Forward the email
    Mail::raw($forwardedBody, function ($mail) use ($message) {
        $mail
            ->from('demo@zyz.com', 'Amazon')
            ->to('demo-1@abc.com', 'Jhon')
            ->subject('Fwd: ' . $message->getHeader('subject'));
    });

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Email forwarded successfully!']);
}


Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the suggested solution didn’t work for me. When I forward an email, if there is a signature or other media (like tables), all HTML elements are stripped, and it returns as plain text.
